# Like condition in MVC4 using lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way for me to do like condition just like query in MVC using lambda? I currently have:

```
return repository.GetAll().Where(
            m => string.(m.Name, name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

So how do I make this into a like condition?

Comment: If you are using MS Sql Database with the [Collation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175.aspx) set to CI (Case Insensitive) you don't need to use the StringComparison enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Contains()` or `StartsWith()` or `EndsWith()` according to your requirement:

```
var filtered= data.Where(x=> x.Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()));
```

in your code:

```
return repository.GetAll().Where(
        m => m.Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()));
```

Comment: a closing parenthesis is missing

Comment: just to clarify, this will generate a like condition like this: (x.Name like '%myVal%') and not (x.Name like 'myval')

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would use `m.Name.Contains`, that isn't possible here since it doesn't support case in-sensitiveness, like you have written down now. (if that is not intentional, use `m.Name.Contains(name)`)

Another option mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring) is the use of `CompareInfo.IndexOf`, but I don't know if it works well with EF.

Give this a try:

```
repository
.GetAll()
.Where
 ( m => CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo
       .IndexOf(m.Name, name, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) > 0
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have managed this before is with raw sql syntax e.g.

```
context.Blogs.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeTable.Name like {0}", name);
```

Comment: Wouldn't you still need `%`?

Comment: only if he needs that in his like comparison. He didnt say he wanted a "Contains" type comparison