# Where clause using LIKE condition in MVC4 lambda

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, lambda, where-clause, sql-like

I want to show results where **w.DrawDate** contains (*LIKE %year%*) the year.

`return View(db.Euro.Select(p => p).Where(w => w.DrawDate == year).ToList());`

As seen in [Like condition in MVC4 using lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035528/like-condition-in-mvc4-using-lambda), i should use the Contains() method, but it isn't available.

So, how can i make `w.DrawDate == year` into `w.DrawDate LIKE %year%`?

Comment: maybe duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346961/linq-where-string-contains-or-string-indexof

Comment: `.Where(w => w.DrawDate.Year == year)`. And you can remove the unnecessary `.Select(p => p)`)

Comment: Thanks for the "unnecessary Select" tip, but let's assume 'DrawDate' is a string and you don't have a Year property, i want to find if "2016" is in "ABCD2016EFGH".

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answer:

```
View(db.Euro.Where(w => w.DrawDate.Contains(year)).ToList());
```

And you're probably just missing a namespace

Comment: Well i `Ctrl + .` on Contains() and it suggests nothing. So, what namespace i am missing to get Contains() method available? The absence of Contains() is critical to my question's existence.

Comment: Actually Contains() is a method for String so you don't need to import a special namespace to use it. If you copy paste my code, does it compile ? Maybe it's just a bug with your intellisense...